# Global alignment using affine gap penalty function

Tags: arrays, alignment, bioinformatics, sequences

I have to write a program that does global alignment between two sequences using affine gap penalty function. The dynamic algorithm (modified Needleman Wunsch) calculates similarity (maximum score that express how similar sequences are) of two given sequences, **s** and **t**. And it takes into account gaps,  blocks of consecutive spaces in a sequence, which are more likely to occur then isolated spaces, by building three 2d arrays. The arrays could be not so formally described as:

array C: keeps maximum score for blocks that end with a character of sequence **s** aligned with a character of sequence **t**;
array BS: keeps maximum score for blocks that end with a character of sequence **t** aligned with a space in sequence **s**

array BT: keeps maximum score for blocks that end with a character of sequence **s** aligned with a space in sequence **t**;
The algorithm has the following recurrence relation:

C[i,j] = v(s[i],t[j]) + max{C[i-1][j-1], BS[i-1][j-1], BT[i-1][j-1]}
BS[i,j] = max{C[i][j-1]-(h+g), BS[i][j-1]-g, BT[i][j-1]-(h+g)}
BT[i,j] = max{C[i-1][j]-(h+g), BS[i-1][j]-(h+g), BT[i-1][j]-g}

** v(s[i],t[i]) = value of match(when both character are identical) or mismatch(when characters are not identical)
Similarity is the highest value among the last value of each array. **The problem is** when I run the program it has a strange behaviour:
For a given pair of sequences, my program gives different values for the same pair of sequences if I change which one is t or s. So, could you please help me to find out why the program has such behaviour? Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong? And about the code, here it goes:

```
    int main (void){

  int mat, mis, h, g,
      sim, i, j, m, n; 
  /* mat = match, mis = mismatch, h = open gap penalty, g = extend gap penalty */

  string s, t;
  s = malloc(1500);
  t = malloc(1500);

    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &mat, &mis, &h, &g);
    scanf("%s", s);
    scanf("%s", t);


    m = strlen(s);
    n = strlen(t);
    int C[m][n], BS[m][n], BT[m][n];  

    C[0][0] = 0;
    for(j = 1; j<= n; j++)
      C[0][j] = -32000;

    for(i = 1; i<= m; i++)
      C[i][0] = -32000;

    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
       BS[0][j] = -(h + g*j);


    for(i = 0; i <= m; i++)
      BS[i][0] = -32000;

      for(j = 0; j <= n; j++)
        BT[0][j] = -32000;

      for(i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        BT[i][0] = -(h + g*i);


for(i = 1; i <= m; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        C[i][j] = align(s[i-1],t[j-1],mat,mis) + max(C[i-1][j-1],BS[i-1][j-1],BT[i-1][j-1]);
        BS[i][j] = max((C[i][j-1]-(h+g)),(BS[i][j-1]-g),(BT[i][j-1])-(h+g));
        BT[i][j] = max((C[i-1][j]-(h+g)),(BS[i-1][j]-(h+g)),(BT[i-1][j]-g));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("c[m][n]: %d bs[m][n]:%d bt[m][n]: %d\n", C[m][n], BS[m][n], BT[m][n]);
    sim = max(C[m][n], BS[m][n], BT[m][n]);
    printf("sim: %d\n", sim);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally find out the problem after trying many printfs, since I don't know how to use debuggers.
The first clue I had was the segmentation fault that gcc was telling me when I tryed to read the sequences (with a relatively big length) from files. It's true that segmentation fault can have several causes, but almost all the times I saw this error in my programs, it occured because I was trying to access a position that actually didn't exist in the array. 
Then the many printfs showed some values in the initialization step, which were different from what the first row and first column of each array should have. I associated the segmentation fault with the strange values from initialization step, and decided to check the declaration step of the arrays as well as all loop conditions. There it was! I simply forgot a very basic feature of any array: if the array has size **n**, you can access from zero to **n-1**. 
 To solve my very newbie error, I added one position for row and column in each array (since the position (0,0) is not associated with any pair of aligned characters) so that each array has size **[m][n]**, where **m** is the (length + 1) of sequence **s**, and **n** is the (length+1) of sequence **t**. Furthermore, I altered all loop conditions to access till **[m-1][n-1]** position. Now the program works fine.